# Capture ok button on return pop-up [Leave this page or stay on this page]

Tags: javascript, browser

i want to capture OK button on pop-up which comes over a return statement while trying to close the browser window so that when i choose to leave the page i can clear the session. Can anybody suggest if it is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You propably want to send an ajax request to a page that clears an user's session - using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for example.

```
confirm_and_logout = function() {
    if (confirm("Do you really want to leave ?")) {
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"logout_page.php"
        });
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return confirm_and_logout();
}
```

Comment: "return false" aint working and its throwing another pop-up asking for leave or stay on page..and if i choose to leave it will not clear the session. Back to same problem. Any other alternative?

Comment: What I mean is you just send an ajax call to a page that destroys the user's session when your confirm box returns true. Which server-side language are you using ? Can you post some code ?

Comment: window.onbeforeunload =  function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to logoff? ")) {
            clearsession();
        }
        else return false; //Need to stop window from getting closed 
    }

Comment: I am using Javascript.Also tried with simple return statement but unable to cature OK button so as to clear session.    window.onbeforeunload =function () {return("Are you sure you want to logoff? ")}

Comment: What is your `clearsession()` code ? Please post it in the question box instead of comments. Also if you want my example to work you need to link with jquery (either download it or add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>` in your header.